Converting micro amount into currency
I'm currently pulling report from Google Ad Manager API. One of the column I'm pulling is a revenue column which is a currency column. After I downloaded the data and save it into CSV file, the revenue column return different than the value from the Google Ad manager website. I've read that the Google ad manager API return the currency value in micros.
Is there any ways in the Google Ad Manager API that can directly change the value to currency value or do I need to create a Python function to change it to the currency?

The value is in micros from the API.
All you need to do is divide it by 1000000 on your end. You cannot have Google do this calculation before you receive it.

https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202008/LineItemService.Money#microAmount thanks, I just found this in the GAM API doc
